# MATLAB: Save command not working

Tags: matlab, while-loop, save, floating-accuracy

I am trying to save some variables at different time steps in a while loop using the 'save' command. It was working in other programs which I had written previously. This is the first time it's not saving. I tried many things like renaming the file to which the data is saved, renaming the script, but it's not working. Here's the sample code:

```
T=0;
while T<300 (time loop)
loop1

loop2
.
.
.
if T==0.01
save('arbit100x100ht10e-3results.txt','Pnew','unew','-ascii','-append')
else if T==0.02
    save('arbit100x100ht10e-3results.txt','Pnew','unew','-ascii','-append')
else if T==0.04
        save('arbit100x100ht10e-3results.txt','Pnew','unew','-ascii','-append')
.
.
. (all the if-if else statements have their respective "end")


T=T+ht; %ht is time step

end (while loop)
```

I am not able to figure out a way out of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is probably conditions like `if T==0.01` that never occur because of floating point precision limit that causes the files not to be saved.

When you're trying to compare two floating-point numbers, be very careful about using `==` to do so.  For example, when you try:

```
T=0.9-0.8;
T==0.1
ans =
     0
```

you see that `T` is never `==0.1` because of the precision limit in how a double is represented in binary form :

```
T-0.1
ans =
   -2.7756e-17
```

An alternative comparison method is to check if the two numbers you're comparing are "close enough" (as expressed by a tolerance) to one another. Try to change the `if` conditions to something that include a threshold tolerance such as:

```
if abs(T-0.01)<1e-10
    ...
```

For an introduction to floating point arithmetic, look at Cleve's Corner article: Floating Points ([PDF](http://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/news_notes/pdf/Fall96Cleve.pdf))

For a more rigorous and detailed information on floating point arithmetic, read  [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating Point Arithmetic](http://docs.sun.com/source/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).